# Flask html5 DateTimeField with picker

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a very simple form, with 2 fields (one DateTime and one Date).  I am trying to get them to render with a picker for each.

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
import wtforms as wtf
import wtforms.fields.html5 as html5
class CaseForm(Form): 
   foo = html5.DateTimeField("Date Time Sample")
   bar = html5.DateField("Date Time Sample")
```

The field foo does not render with a picker widget, but bar does.  I can see from the code for the html5 fields that there is a widget associated with the DateTimeField.

Any ideas on how to render a picker for DateTime fields

Comment: I know it was long time ago but did you find the solution for this issue. Date Time control is not appearing for me either, I am using the same code as you.

Comment: I've reproduced this problem as well and am still searching for a solution.

Comment: Perhaps you need javascript imported into your template

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem,after much frustration I ended up using `DateTimeLocalField`.

Comment: Works perfectly in Chrome based browsers but not Firefox. In Firefox only the Calendar picker shows, not the time.